# Periodic Solutions for the system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having lots of troubles with proving that systems do not have periodic solutions. For example,

**PROBLEM:**

Prove that the system:

$\dot x = A(t)x$ **has no periodic solutions but the trivial**, where

$A(t) = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2+sin(t) \\
    4+cos^{2}(t) & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

My naive attempt has to try to calculate the solutions explicitly but I went no where. My other idea is find some criterion for perturbed systems (i.e $\dot x = (A+B(t))x$) which allows me to prove periodicity but I couldn't find any.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated, thanks guys <3

Comment: A thought, perhaps diagonalise the system?

Comment: The thing is that, if we diagonalise it we end up with something no really treatable haha at least not for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your system, 
$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{d}{dt} (x(t) y(t)) &= \dot{x}(t) y(t) + x(t) \dot{y}(t)\cr & = 
  x \left( t \right)  ^{2} \left( 4+ \left( \cos \left( 
t \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) +  y \left( t \right)  ^
{2} \left( 2+\sin \left( t \right)  \right)\cr 
&> 0}$$ as long as $(x(t), y(t)) \ne (0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but I have no idea of what you just did, and have not seen anything similar before haha. Please, could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm writing your $x(t)$ as $\pmatrix{x(t)\cr y(t)\cr}$.
If the solution is periodic, either $x(t) y(t)$ is constant or its derivative is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.